# Printing Value of String Variable defined in C# Function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I defined a function in asp.net and assigned this function to a Button click. 
In this function I have fetched a column from SQL server and assigned its values to a string variable.
I want to see the value of this string.

Is there anyway in C# through which i can print the value of this string?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Uma_Trial_2
{
    public partial class Trial1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string final;
        protected string Page_Load(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
       // {
           // if (IsPostBack)
            //Initial is !IsPostBack
          //  {
               // BindData();
          //  }
       // }
        //protected string BindData(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            DropDownList ddlMul = new DropDownList();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXXX@$$w0rd");
            conn.Open();
            string cmdstr = "select DISTINCT [Month_Abbr] from  [XXXXXXXXXXXX]";
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, conn);
            adp.Fill(ds);

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlMul = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownMultiple1");

                if (ddlMul != null)
                {
                    ddlMul.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    ddlMul.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Month_Abbr"].ColumnName.ToString();
                    ddlMul.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Month_Abbr"].ColumnName.ToString();
                    ddlMul.DataBind();
                }
            }

            List<String> Month_Abbr_list = new List<string>();

            foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in ddlMul.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    Month_Abbr_list.Add(item.Value);
                }

            }
            final = "(" + String.Join(",", Month_Abbr_list.ToArray()) + ")";  
            return final;


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You can keep breakpoint at return final and check values there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Response.Write(StringVariableHere);
```

or

Create asp label

```
<asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" />
```

and

set text property of label

```
lblResult.Text = StringVariableHere;
```

or

You can use Visual Studio debugger to check variable values by putting breakpoint at desired location.

Comment: I tried using the Response.write()...but it was showing a warning like "Unreachable Code detected".

Comment: @user3524441 Could you please edit your question and add your code.  So I can have look into it.

Comment: I tried using Label control . It was executing, but could not see any label when i published the dashboard in the browser.

Comment: @user3524441 How you are calling this function " protected string Page_Load(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)" or where you are using this function

Comment: @rahul...I have a multiple Dropdown filter in my dashboard. So when i select multiple values in the filter and Click 'OK' button embedded in the filter, then that will trigger the page load.
I want to Use the Selected values and pass on to WHERE IN clause in the data source query of the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Could u show the String or a part of your Code?

there are some Methods to show your Value:

```
printf("\n yourString:");

Console.WriteLine(yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an asp Label control, set it as runat = server and access the control using name property to put string value in browser.